# Class naming and namespaces: best practice as an extension author?

Tags: php, best-practice, coding-standards, autoloading

Noting these related questions 
([1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/where-to-put-api-wrapper-class-in-an-extension)
[2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15810/does-class-autoloading-not-work-in-standalone-phpunit-testing)
[3](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11357/how-to-develop-extension-that-relies-on-libs-brought-in-by-composer))
and these two wiki pages
([1](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension)
[2](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/The+codebase#Thecodebase-Namespaces))
and the [psr-0 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), I remain a bit lost about current best practice in CiviCRM extensions!

So if I have an extenstion `org.goodfolk.magichtml`

Would I put my classes in

```
org.goodfolk.magichtml/Civi/MagicHtml/
```

So in `org.goodfolk.magichtml/Civi/MagicHtml/HtmlFlash.php` I would have the following:

`<?php
    namespace org.goodfolk.magichtml/MagicHtml;
    class HtmlFlash {
      public function squirmLeft() {};
      public function squirmRight() {};
    }`

Is that correct?

or can it be simplified to:

`org.goodfolk.magichtml/Civi/HtmlFlash.php`:

`<?php
    namespace org.goodfolk.magichtml;
    class HtmlFlash {
      public function squirmLeft() {};
      public function squirmRight() {};
    }`

Comment: note I deliberately put multiword class and extension in the example as I'd like to clarity capitalization and underscore patterns too

Comment: and proper handling html/HTML/Html (which also relates to SQL, API, PDF etc etc etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The conventional approach

Generally, the safe play is to make a file like `<myextension>/CRM/MyExtension/MyClass.php`:

```
<?php
class CRM_MyExtension_MyClass { ...}
```

(Be sure to match the capitalization of files and classes.)

Most documentation and tooling is based on `CRM_*` conventions, and a handful of things in core (such as `civicrm_payment_processor_type.class_name`) make quirky assumptions which only work with `CRM_*` classes.

*How it works*: In civix-based extensions, the default `hook_civicrm_config` adds your extension to the `include_path`. The classloader `CRM_Core_ClassLoader` searches the `include_path` automatically for `CRM_*` classes.

*Critique:* In older PHP projects, it was common to automatically link the class-loading with the `include_path`, but in large codebases this can lead to a large number of file-system checks. Now-a-days many frameworks will reduce lookups by pre-generating some kind of map (namespaces<=>directories or classes<=>files).

### The PSR-4 approach (Civi v4.7+)

PSR-4 is a more contemporary technique in which you explicitly map a directory to a namespace. Many PHP developers have been exposed to [PSR-4 through `composer.json`](https://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer). Civi v4.7 adds `CRM_Extension_ClassLoader`; with this, you can use `info.xml` to declare similar mappings:

```
<extension key="..." type="module">
  ...
  <classloader>
    <psr4 prefix="My\Namespace\" path="src" />
  </classloader>
  ...
</extension>
```

In this case, the file `<myextension>/src/Foo.php` would look like:

```
<?php
namespace My\Namespace;
class Foo { ... }
```

In terms of lookup performance and caching, this should be better than `CRM_Core_ClassLoader`. However, it doesn't have full parity with `CRM_*` in terms of documentation / tooling / testing.

## Custom class loader

You should be able to register your own class-loaders -- e.g. just call `spl_autoload_register(...)` in your module's main PHP file (perhaps in `hook_civicrm_config`). If you do this, I suggest following a convention like PSR-0 or PSR-4.

Compared to the PSR-4/Civi v4.7 approach above:

- Pro: Should be compatible with any version of Civi
- Con: Requires more lines of code
- Con: Has the same issue of negligible documentation / tooling / testing

## PHPUnit Base Classes

There is an issue if you want to write a custom base-class for PHPUnit tests within an extension -- which is the topic of [Does class autoloading not work in standalone phpunit testing?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15810/does-class-autoloading-not-work-in-standalone-phpunit-testing)

Comment: Thanks Tim, so since I'm on 4.6 currently path of least resistance is `The conventional approach` then? There's no standard backport example for 4.6 laying about?

Comment: sorry I know I could nut this out but if i do my own home grown I will exacerbate the "negligible documentation / tooling / testing" problem!

Answer (score 0):

In general, when developing extensions I would take a look at the existing ones authored by the core team or by heavily active contributors. To give some importance on my suggestion below I just checked widely used cms independent extensions available and landed at https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount.

Extensions that I wrote and most I know hold classes under `<tld.domain.ext>/CRM/ExtensionName/` and follow php's naming conventions there. API methods are located under `api/v3/` and named in api manner (classes reflecting api, methods reflecting actions).

Comment: Thanks @Neilo - I'm just wondering about best practice since php 5.3 became standard and introduced namespacing. (see the comments [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/The+codebase#Thecodebase-Namespaces) that imply a new pattern but aren't clear on if it applies to extensions or not.

Comment: Jesus, sorry! Reading the "When to use" column in the doc you linked I dare to say  I'd know what to use in *my* extensions. But my suggestions wouldn't be more than hardly educated guesses. A question for more advanced people.